# How to create a time series dataframe from a 1D numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, time-series

I have the following numpy array S ( actual array is bigger) :

```
 S = np.array([200,210,230, 250, 270, 290, 300, 350,400])
```

with sample interval of 40 µs, i want to create the following dataframe where i have a time ( in seconds) column and value column as below:

```
 time    value
 0        200
 0.00004  210
 0.00008  230
 0.00012  250
 0.00016  270
 0.00020  290
 0.00024  300
    .
    .
    .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create yout time vector (with [numpy.arange](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) for example), then use it as the time column of your pandas DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

S = np.array([200,210,230, 250, 270, 290, 300, 350,400])

dt = 0.00004

d = {
    'time' : np.arange(0, len(S)*dt, dt),
    'value' : S
}

print(pd.DataFrame(d))
```

output

```
      time  value
0  0.00000    200
1  0.00004    210
2  0.00008    230
3  0.00012    250
4  0.00016    270
5  0.00020    290
6  0.00024    300
7  0.00028    350
8  0.00032    400
```

Personally, I really like to use the Dataframe() constructor that takes a dictionary as argument. It is clean and clear.